# Google Refine Reconciliation: How to auto-replace with result text

Tags: google-refine

Let's say I have cell like this:
"Nat. Taiwan Normal Univ., Taipei"

Once I do reconciliation, I get this:
Nat. Taiwan Normal Univ., Taipei
V V Create new topic
Search for match

Then I click on "Search for match" and get a drop down result:
"National Taiwan Normal University"

2 questions:
- How to I output the result text ("National Taiwan Normal University") in a separate or same column?
- Is it possible to output the country, which the result university is in, to a separate column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GREL expression `cell.recon.match.name` will get you the name.  Put it in a separate column, so you don't lose the recon object.

Using "Add column from Freebase" will allow you to add the property `/location/location/contained_by` with a constraint of `"type":"/location/country"`

Comment: Thanks Tom. That was very helpful. Just another question: How do I auto-match all cells to the first drop-down results from "Search for match"?


There's an option "Match each cell to its best candidate". But often, I find the result from "Search for match" better than Reconciliation. Is there a difference?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it meets your needs.  As for the matching process, there's really no way to do what you want currently.  It works (or doesn't) they way it does currently because of quirks in the backend services which aren't under Refine's control.  Hopefully these will get ironed out as Freebase finishes the transition from the old Metaweb infrastructure to the new Google infrastructure.